# How to make `TextCell` `Detail` appear on the right of `Text` next to `Disclosure` arrow in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

So it's my first time to use Xamarin Forms `TextCell`. I want the `Detail` text of the cell to appear on the right side next to the `Disclosure` icon like the image below.

PS: Image not mine.

[image]

I have tried searching about this but couldn't find any reference. Anyone knows how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native iOS cells have a `UITableViewCellStyle` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcellstyle)), you can set this by implementing a [custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/).

This should probably look something like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (TextCell), typeof (RightDetailSample.iOS.TextCellRenderer))]
namespace RightDetailSample.iOS
{
    public class TextCellRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.TextCellRenderer
    {

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            var textCell = (TextCell)item;

            var fullName = item.GetType ().FullName;
            var cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell (fullName) as CellTableViewCell;
            if (cell == null) {
                cell = new CellTableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, fullName);
            } else {
                cell.Cell.PropertyChanged -= cell.HandlePropertyChanged;
            }

            cell.Cell = textCell;
            textCell.PropertyChanged += cell.HandlePropertyChanged;
            cell.PropertyChanged = this.HandlePropertyChanged;

            cell.TextLabel.Text = textCell.Text;

            cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = textCell.Detail;


            UpdateBackground (cell, item);

            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how you set the `UITableViewCellStyle.Value1` in the constructor of a new cell. It is not possible to set it afterwards. When implemented it looks like this:[image: Result]

A sample project can be found [here](https://github.com/jfversluis/RightDetailSample).

Comment: Thank you very much! That's perfect!

Comment: This example is good for static data, but it doesn't address what happens if the underlying value changes. If the user changes English to "French", the underlying viewmodel is changed but the UItableview never refreshes.
The only way I've gotten it to work so far is by adding...
textCell.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => tv.ReloadData(); This is not a criticism by the way, just something to point out to those expecting it to reflect viewmodel changes.

Answer (score 0):

TextCell has static format title under it detail, if you want to make your custom cell design you should use [Custom Cell](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance/)